# An error with __dirname variable in nodejs using express

Tags: node.js, express

I have an error with directories and paths.

Look, this is my server config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

const morgan = require("morgan");
const multer = require("multer");
const express = require("express");
const erroHandler = require("errorhandler");
const routes = require("../routes/index");

module.exports = app => {
  app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
  console.log("0. " + __dirname);
  let parent = path.normalize(__dirname + "/src/");
  console.log("1. " + parent);
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
  let d = app.get("views");
  console.log("2. " + d);
   app.engine(
    ".hbs",
     exphbs({
         extName: ".hbs",
         defaultLayout: "main",
         partialsDir: [ path.join(__dirname, '../views') ],
         layoutDir: path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'layouts'),
         helpers: require("../helpers")
    })
 );
  app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

  // middlewares
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
  app.use(
    multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, "../public/upload/temp") }).single(
      "image"
    )
  );
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(express.json());

  //routes
  routes(app);

  // static files
  app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

  // errorhandlers
  if ("development" === app.get("env")) {
    app.use(erroHandler);
  }

  return app;
};
```

And I get some error like this:

I know it's not the extension but the route. I will show you my directories:

[image]

I am getting this error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Diesan
>   Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare views folder like this

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
```

And change the app.engine  like this

```
  app.engine(
    ".hbs",
     exphbs({
         extName: ".hbs",
         defaultLayout: "main",
         partialsDir: [ path.join(__dirname, '../views') ]
         layoutDir: path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'layouts'),
         helpers: require("../helpers")
    })
 );
```

I produced the same error on my side and then fixed it hopefully 90 percent it will do the trick

Comment: No, I get this error Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\server\views"

Comment: I'm really desperate, it took me a week with that mistake. Any solution suits me.

Comment: Ok dont worry you will get help can you please give me git repo ? if You have

Comment: And when this error occur after requesting which route this error occurs can you please share the route also

Comment: My first console.log() return me this route: 0. C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\server, my second return me this route: 1. C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\server\src\ and the last one, this route: 2. C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\server\src\views That should not go into the server folder, but exit. When I do it, it gives me another error.

Comment: I modified the question with the solution you gave me, and I also put the new error. What am I wrong now?

Comment: You mentioned 2 errors in the question are these both are occurring if not the please paste the new one here

Comment: I modified, the new error is Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Comment: Instead of this defaultLayout: "main", inside app.engine try to use this defaultLayout: "main.hbs", and let me know what happen

Comment: The same: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views\layouts\main.hbs' the problem is the route it's should be 'C:\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\views\layouts\main.hbs' for some reason omit the src folder

Answer (score 1):

Your path to your layout is incorrect this is what the error message is telling you 
 looking at your folder structure `\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\views\layouts\main.handlebars` should be this: `\Users\Diesan Romero\Desktop\redsocial\src\views\layouts\main.handlebars`. You are missing the **src** directory between your redsocial and views directories.

Comment: How Can I fix that God? I know that's the problem.